# problem when deploy smart contract in Quorum using web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, java, web3j, quorum

I'm using web3J when i try to deploy contract i get

```
Error processing transaction request: Non-200 status code: &{Status:400 Bad Request StatusCode:400 Proto:HTTP/1.1 ProtoMajor:1 ProtoMinor:1 Header:map[Date:[Mon, 29 May 2017 13:03:02 GMT] Server:[Warp/3.2.8]] Body:0xc425668cc0 ContentLength:-1 TransferEncoding:[chunked] Close:false Uncompressed:false Trailer:map[] Request:0xc42045a690 TLS:<nil>}
```

I used this methods

```
ClientTransactionManager transactionManager = new ClientTransactionManager(quorum,
            "0x0fbdc686b912d7722dc86510934589e0aaf3b55a", Arrays.asList(""));


    BigInteger contract = InstanceOkoro.deploy(quorum, transactionManager, GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT, BigInteger.ZERO)
            .get().getGasPrice();
```

with

```
private static final BigInteger GAS_PRICE = new BigInteger("0");
private static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = new BigInteger("900000");
```

Comment: In your Quorum node configuration is the account that you're using for the transactions unlocked 0x0fbdc686b912d7722dc86510934589e0aaf3b55a? Also, can you provide the JSON-RPC output associated with the requests - see https://docs.web3j.io/trouble.html#i-want-to-see-details-of-the-json-rpc-requests-and-responses?

Comment: Can you please give me a sample Quorum code, how you called your application binary, executed the functions. ?

Answer (score -2):

I resolve it by changing GAS_LIMIT !

Comment: Changed it to what? Could you improve your answer?

Comment: I am also getting the same error when deploying contract privately in quorum could you please explain how you resolved it